# Rails association fails on Heroku but works on local box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, heroku, associations, rails-routing

Why would I get **NoMethodError** on my Heroku app when the same code  works flawlessly on my local setup?

The error is triggered by this code:

```
@customer = Customer.find(1)
@customer.responses.create(:offer_id => '1', :digit => '2')
```

That code works as intended on my local server and in my local Rails console.

However, on Heroku the above code triggers NoMethodError:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `responses' for #<Customer:0x7f7bcbee3808>):
```

The **Response** model is tied to the **Customer** model by means of **belongs_to :customer**

Additionally, I can login to the Heroku console and run this without any problems:

```
Response.create(:offer_id => '1', :customer_id => '1', :digit => '2')
```

So if the above works and both versions work fine on my local box, why would the association fail on Heroku?

--

Running Rails 3.0.6 and tested on Heroku Ruby 1.8.7 and Ruby 1.9.2

Databases are identical on Heroku and on my local box.

Comment: Is `:belongs_to :customer` a type. Should be `belongs_to :customer`

Comment: If you are using R3 you should be using Ruby >1.9.1

Comment: @Sam why the recommendation for > 1.9.1? Are there particular issues with RoR 3 on 1.8.7 ?

Comment: 1.8.7 is the default with Heroku but with my experience I have noticed problems like the one you are stating. Fine on local until Heroku and it's usually something to do with rails version or ruby version.

Comment: @Sam it was indeed a typo in my post, fixed. Also, I went ahead and upgraded to 1.9.2 per your suggestion but unfortunately the error persists, i.e. no difference.

Comment: well, at least you know that's not it. can you `heroku logs` and post the applicable code?

Comment: also make sure you have `has_many :responses` in your Customer model.

Comment: That's weird, what you're describing should work. I don't have an explanation for you, but I have found the heroku staff to be very helpful with this kind of mysterious problem. Definitely submit a ticket to them if you haven't already. Good luck!

Comment: @Sam I have Expanded logging enabled but unfortunately it contains exactly the same error message I get in the Heroku Rails console, all it shows is the message I posted above and the corresponding file:line where it was triggered. Also, I confirmed that has_many :responses is indeed in my Customer model. I would imagine my local version of the code would not work had I left it out.

Comment: @Andrew I went ahead and submitted it to Heroku, I'll post the response here if we figure out what the problem is..

Comment: Do you have any migrations that you've run locally but not on Heroku? `heroku rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when something like this doesn't work it indicates you're missing a `has_many` association. You need to define **both** the `belongs_to` and `has_many` sides of the association if you wish to access them both.

By the sounds of it, if it's working on your local machine but not Heroku then it would be because you haven't pushed the changes to the Heroku server and restarted the console there. Please make sure you have pushed the changes and try again.

Comment: I hate to admit it but it turned out to be just that. I was positive I pushed all the code upstream, but it turned out to be a commit discrepancy between master on my local box and master on the server. Heroku's version was missing the association. A dumb mistake but a good lesson to check the basics before everything else.

Comment: It reminds me of an old adage from a college programming course: if you're sure all your code is correct, but it still isn't working, then one of the things you're sure is right is wrong. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Marco, I thought about this a bit, and I have a few guesses for you to try. Before you do either of these, restart your app. Sometimes that does miracles.

```
heroku restart
```

Ok, now, try in console just

```
@customer.responses
```

What does that return? I assume it should be `[]`. Maybe doing some inspection etc. of that can give us insights here. If you build and associate a response manually can you get it to show up?

Second, your no method error is on `responses`, not on `create`, so whatever you type after that probably doesn't matter, BUT, are your `offer_id` and `digit` fields integers? If so, try creating them using integers, not strings. PostgreSQL is so fragile compared to MySQL or SQLite, I've had loads of issues that trace back to my unfamiliarity working with Postgre prior to developing on Heroku.

```
@customer.responses.create(:offer_id=>1,:digit=>3)
```

That probably doesn't matter but it's worth checking out.

The other thing to check is all your callbacks and validations etc. Is anything failing? It may not seem related but I've had issues before where things acted very weird because of seemingly tiny silent failures in a callback that I had overlooked. I'm sure you're testing as you go, but if you've got shallow test coverage anywhere on this model you might as well use this bug hunt as a chance to beef it up :)

Sympathies on the error, I don't know if any of this will help, but good luck! Please post if Heroku staff find the issue, I'd be very interested to learn from it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is how you are creating the response:

```
@customer.responses.create(:offer_id => '1', :digit => '2')
```

You might want to try this instead.

```
Response.create(:offer_id => '1', :digit => '2', :customer_id => 1)
```

Comment: The first version should work just fine. It does, in fact, just not on Heroku. My code is almost exactly the same as the code posted here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Also, I have very similar code for different models in other parts of my application and it works flawlessly on Heroku and on my local server.